# count based on two columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql

My table in Mysql is like this:

```
 IP       ID     area
 aaa      A        I
 aaa      A        I
 aaa      B        I  
 aaa      C        II
 bbb      A        I
 bbb      B        III
 ccc      B        I
```

Now I want to calculate for each area value, how many different (IP, ID) pairs are there?

How can I use both IP and ID as a whole dataset to do this?

I don't think the following query is correct:

```
SELECT area, count (distinct IP, ID) from video GROUP BY area ORDER BY COUNT (distinct ip, ID)
```

So does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT area, count(*) as distinctCount FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT IP, ID, area FROM video) distinctVideos 
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*), CONCAT_WS(' ',IP,ID) as yourTitle FROM video GROUP BY yourTitle
```

should do